# Android FirebaseError: Firebase: A network AuthError (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-oauth, google-signin

I am in the process of migrating to Expo 49 for my React Native app. This has lead me to also migrate my Google authentication to `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` opposed to the deprecated `expo-auth-session`.

I have had success with this on iOS, but Android is having issues.

When I launch the app, and then press the `Sign in with Google` button, the phone seems to lose connection, as I get logs telling me when my sockets have lost connection and when they reconnect, as well as the error:

```
[FirebaseError: Firebase: A network AuthError (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. (auth/network-request-failed).]
```

Just to clear up any other points, I have double checked all of my SHA-1 fingerprints, I have one each for `debug` and `release`. These have been added to my Firebase project, and I have the up to date `google-services.json`.

My code is as follows:

```js
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.googleWebClientId,
      iosClientId: Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.googleiOSClientId,
    })

    const googleSignIn = async (): Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential | void> => {
      try {
        await GoogleSignin.signOut()
        const userInformation = await GoogleSignin.signIn()
        const googleCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(userInformation.idToken)
        const result = await auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential)
        return result
      } catch (error: any) {
        // handle errors
      }
    }
```

The below is my firebase setup:

```js
import 'expo-firestore-offline-persistence'
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
import 'firebase/compat/storage'
import 'firebase/compat/functions'

const firebaseApp = firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.app()
  : firebase.initializeApp(Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.firebaseConfig)

firebaseApp.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true, merge: true })

firebaseApp.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)

const firestore = firebaseApp.firestore()
const auth = firebaseApp.auth()
const storage = firebaseApp.storage()
const functions = firebase.functions()

const { GoogleAuthProvider } = firebase.auth
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider()

if (__DEV__) {
  const origin = Constants?.expoConfig?.hostUri?.split(':').shift() || 'localhost'
  console.log('Origin: ', origin)
  auth.useEmulator(`http://${origin}:9099/`)
  firestore.useEmulator(origin, 8080)
  storage.useEmulator(origin, 9199)
  functions.useEmulator(origin, 5001)
}

export { firestore, auth, storage, functions, GoogleAuthProvider, googleProvider }
```

I checked the Android emulator settings, and ensured that `No proxy` was enabled, I also saw some posts talking about the DNS of Firebase, and to swap `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, I am not too sure what exactly that was suggesting, but I tried setting my `const origin = '127.0.0.1'`, not sure if that is what that meant.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of this line?

```
console.log('Origin: ', origin);
```

It should be 10.0.2.2, not 127.0.0.1
If the output is 127.0.0.1, then firebase will try to connect the localhost (127.0.0.1) of the Android emulator, not the host machine.

Have a look at: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking